# using a value holding variable for column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Whats wrong with this query? For example `$brand` holds the value `apple`
Then I get the error `unknown column 'apple'`

Can anyone see the problem?

```
if(isset($_GET['brand']) ? $_GET['brand'] : 0) {
   $brand = (isset($_GET['brand']) ? $_GET['brand'] : 0);
   $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE brand = $brand  AND 
                       status = 1 ORDER BY id DESC")
    OR die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Edit:
With error checking

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);   
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

I get this error
'Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Unknown column 'apple' in 'where clause'''

Comment: do `WHERE brand = '$brand'` or `WHERE brand = '".$brand."'` and make sure you have a column called "brand"

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and need to learn basic SQL syntax as well.

Comment: i still get the error

Comment: "' .$brand. '" Use concatenation

Comment: Well then, you don't have a column named "apple" (or brand), do you? Make sure you don't have a space in your column name too.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

 mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: Plus, you're not looking for a column named that, you're looking for a value called "apple" that's inside the "brand" column.

Comment: I have a column named 'brand' the value 'apple' is in the variable $brand and is a value in the 'brand' column. I have edited my question with the error given by the error reporting you asked.........

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_GET['brand'])) 
{
   $brand = $_GET['brand'];
   $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE brand = {$brand}  AND 
                   status = 1 ORDER BY id DESC")
   OR die(mysqli_error($link));
}
```

Comment: Still the same. I have edited my question with some error reporting if that makes anything any clearer.............